# How to execute a PHP closure which is stored (as string) in database

Tags: php, closures

I want some entities to execute extra code (which returns html), stored in their own data, in database. For this **I am trying to store a closure in a field of the table**, and execute it after retrieving it.

The closure gives me the opportunity to encapsulate the script (in a scope) and execute it whenever I want after obtaining the database.

The problem is that it doesn't work. Error: 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined `function function () {...`.

(Premise: I know that 'serialization of Closure is not allowed')

**Example of the closure stored in database:**

```
function() {
    return '<h1>Today is '.date('d/m/Y').'</h1>';
};
```

**Retrieve data and execution of the closure:**

```
//example of retrieve
$sql = "SELECT field FROM table";
$q = $link->query($sql);
$row = $q->fetchRow();

//execution, var must be contain the html processed in the closure
$var = $row['field']();
```

Can anyone help me with the error or give me another idea to build this scenario?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `eval` the php code.

```php
//execution, var must be contain the html processed in the closure
eval('$fn='.$row['field']);
$var = $fn();
```

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
> allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
> If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
> use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
> provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Document: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: OK. It runs. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it but... for now I will code it by this way. I had tried to use `eval()` before differently with no success. Thank you!.

Comment: I think `php-lua` is more applicable here, it runs lua script in sandbox, but you need convert your php code stored in DB to lua

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use printf and store the format string in the database? In that case you won't need an (evil) `eval`. The format string is printf or sprintf is quite powerful, but cannot solve all cases. But you could write a custom printf like function that could do what you wanted.

Comment: I'm aware of the risk of using `eval()`, but I'm afraid it will require more complex logic than formatting a string with printf. Thanks.

Comment: I understand. From you example that is not completely clear. Could you elaborate on a more complex example?